# fb share button no of shares not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get the number of shares options near my fb button...
    can you guys tell me how to achieve it...
    i got the f button but i am not able to achieve the number of shares option..
    for twitter it shows count but for fb it doesnt show the count...
    providing my code below...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=243027682401976&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/"></div>
```

Comment: Number of likes count or share?

Comment: @AliasgarRajpiplawala: thanks for your reply...can you tell me how to achieve both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pointing the URL you want to share to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

See the data-href attribute of the div.

Use the code generator to point it to your URL instead of that one.